# Why am I getting a FileNotFoundException (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) in Java?

Tags: java, io, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to create a program where it takes simple input and writes it to a file. Problem is, when it tries to open the file to write to it, I get the error: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: ‪C:\Users\bobdu\eclipse-workspace\SHIPTesting.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)." I even have a very simple program where I get the same error:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class OutputTesting {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
     try
     {
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("‪C:\\Users\\bobdu\\eclipse-workspace\\SHIPTesting.txt"));
        outputStream.println("Output line 1");
        outputStream.println("Output line 2");
        outputStream.close();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        System.exit(0);
    }
 }

}
```

The file does exist for sure, I can find it in my directory. Thank you in advance for helping me.

Answer (score 4):

You have an extra non-printable character in your path string.  It survived the copy paste as well, so i was able to reproduce your error.  Here is a test:

```
    String yours = "‪C:\\Users\\bobdu\\eclipse-workspace\\SHIPTesting.txt";
    String retyp = "C:\\Users\\bobdu\\eclipse-workspace\\SHIPTesting.txt";

    System.out.println("yours len="+yours.length()+", retype=" + retyp.length());
```

The output is

```
yours len=49, retype=48
```

Comment: Looks like there are three extra bytes before "C:": `0xE2`, `0x80`, `0xAA`. If you change the charset encoding for source code files in your IDE to Latin-1 you'd actually see visible characters there.

Comment: @Magdrop Thank you so much for your help. I was able to fix the problem by just hand typing the path name. Do you know what caused this though? All I did was copy and paste the path name from the properties tab of the file.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Thank you so much for your help. I was able to fix the problem by just hand typing the path name. Do you know what caused this though? All I did was copy and paste the path name from the properties tab of the file

Comment: @DemonSlayer730 I'm not even sure where to start guessing for that.  Do you perhaps have multiple language inputs?  I usually not going to worry about it until it happens more frequently.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bad character in your path.  When I try to paste it into eclipse, I get:

[image]