# servlet is showing java.io.FileNotFoundException: ?E:\guru99\test.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My servlet is showing this exception but the file exist at that location.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ?E:\guru99\test.txt (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Servlet Code,

```
   @WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/image_download"})
    public class image_download extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            String gurufile = "test.txt";
                    String gurupath = "‪E:\\guru99\\";
            response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + gurufile + "\"");

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(gurupath + gurufile);

            int i;
            while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
                out.write(i);
            }
            fileInputStream.close();
            out.close();
        }


        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    }
```

I want to download the file from the link I provided.

Comment: You really gave a file whose name starts with `?`? And why are you setting the Content-type twice?

Comment: Even though partial stack trace is able to point to problem, You should paste full stack trace & that would have helped others better.

Comment: no i don't put the ? there. it was added automatically in exception

Comment: It's only in the exception because it was in the filename. The answer you accepted says the same thing. You didn't answer my second question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a FileNotFoundException (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713047/why-am-i-getting-a-filenotfoundexception-the-filename-directory-name-or-volum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is duplicate of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51713047/why-am-i-getting-a-filenotfoundexception-the-filename-directory-name-or-volum)

As when I tried to copy your code to my eclipse , I got same prompt about **Save Problems**. Somewhere there is an invalid character & string  with that char can't be parsed into valid file path.

I manually retyped values for `String gurufile`  & `String gurupath` instead of copy pasting your code & it worked successfully. Culprit seems `String gurupath`.

Second point is usage of **try-with-resource** ( though that has nothing to do with your issue ) instead of explicitly trying to close out resources,

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
    String gurufile = "test.txt";
    String gurupath = "D:\\guru99\\";
    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + gurufile + "\"");
    try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(gurupath + gurufile);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();) {
        int i;
        while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(i);
        }
    }
```

Copy - paste my code to see if this resolves your problem.

Comment: np, are you using multi lingual keyboard or something like that ( i.e. using other languages ) ? or did you copy code from somewhere else? Its important that you figure out root cause to avoid future problems.

Comment: sir i have another problem in my code in another page can you checked my code and help me using teamViewer or any other resourse

Comment: Hi Sorry, I was on vacation. If you have other issues, I think, you can put another SO question & others can also pitch in.